# как заставить меню bootstrap4 уходить в collapse раньше?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

Есть меню navbar как сделать чтобы элементы уходили в toggler при ширине 1200px и меньше

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <nav class="mb-1 navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" style="margin-bottom: 0rem!important;padding-bottom: 0.3rem!important">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="img/logo.png" height="30" alt="Лого">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent-4" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent-4" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent-4">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item" style="color:white;">
                <a class="align-center" href="index.html">&nbsp;Главная</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item" style="color:white;">
                <a class="align-center" href="profnastil.html" target="_blank">&nbsp;Профнастил</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item" style="color:white;">
                <a class="align-center" href="metalocherepiza.html" target="_blank">&nbsp;Металочерепица</a>
              </li>
                <li class="nav-item" style="color:white;">
                  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span class="align-bottom">&nbsp;тел 066 00 00 000</span>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <button class="btn_top" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaltel">Заказать звонок</button>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="modaltel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header text-center">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold" style="color:white;text-transform:uppercase;">Заказ товара</h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="font-size:30px;font-weight:800;color:white;">X
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body mx-3" style="padding-bottom:0px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <p class="text-center" style="color:white;">Наша цель экономить ваше время, деньги и нервы. Оставьте свой номер, мы перезвоним, дадим консультацию...</p>
                                    <form action="success.php" method="post">
                                        <div class="container">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 text-center" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                                                    <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона" required style="width:100%;position:relative;margin-bottom:0;height:50px;border-radius:8px;border-color:white;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;padding-left:10px;border-style:solid;border-width:2px;" /><input type="hidden" name="typeform" value="">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                                                    <img src="img/arrform1.png" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:80px;">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 text-right" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                                                    <img src="img/arrform2.png" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:80px;">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 text-center" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                                                    <input type="text" maxlength="45" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required style="width:100%;position:relative;margin-bottom:0;height:50px;border-radius:8px;border-color:white;margin-bottom:5px;padding-left:10px;border-style:solid;border-width:2px;" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <div class="row" style="background:white;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 text-right" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                                                    <button class="btn text-center" type="submit" name="button" style="border-width:2px;border-color:black;font-weight:800;background:white;">Заказать обратный звонок</button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                                                    <img src="img/arrright.png" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:60px;position:relative;top:30px;">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 text-left" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                                                    <img src="img/tel.png" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:60px;">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Почему бы Вам не сделать воспроизводимый пример?

Comment: @humster_spb добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените в теге nav класс navbar-expand-lg на navbar-expand-xl

Comment: а можно сделать ещё раньше? от 1400px

Comment: @Alexander путём переписывания переменных в корне bootstrap

Comment: @Alexander, залезаете в исходный код Бутстрапа, смотрите, какие нужные Вам классы в какой момент как себя ведут, и в своих кастомных стилях переопределяете это поведение: https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css